# Mock Patch check parent class method call

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, mocking, patch

I want to unit test this class method `update`

```
class EmployeeUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, data):
        shift_types = data.pop('shift_types', None)
        instance = super().update(instance, data)
        self.update_shift_type(instance, shift_types)
        return instance
```

I am doing this

```
class TestEmployeeUpdateSerializer(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company, self.user, self.header = create_user_session()
        self.serializer = EmployeeUpdateSerializer()

    def test_update(self):
        employee = self.user

        with patch.object(self.serializer, 'update') as update:
            with patch.object(self.serializer, 'update_shift_type') as update_shift_type:
                res = self.serializer.update(employee, dict())

                update.assert_called_once_with(employee, dict())
                update_shift_type.assert_called_once_with(employee, None)

                self.assertEqual(res, employee)
```

But this gives me an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shahzadfarukh/my-croft/backend/account/tests/test_employee_serializers.py", line 222, in test_update
    update_shift_type.assert_called_once_with(employee, None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 830, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'update_shift_type' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

Please help me! is something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have mocked `update`, so it's original code won't get called. If you want to test what `update` calls, you have to call the original version, and mock only functions/methods called within `update`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Can you please help me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mocked `update`, so its original code won't get called. If you want to test what `update` calls, you have to call the original version, and mock only functions/methods called within the update. Assuming the base class is imported like `import serializers`, you could do something like this (untested)

```
class TestEmployeeUpdateSerializer(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company, self.user, self.header = create_user_session()
        self.serializer = EmployeeUpdateSerializer()

     @patch('serializers.ModelSerializer.update')
     @patch('serializers.ModelSerializer.update_shift_type')
     def test_update(self, mocked_update_shift_type, mocked_update):
         employee = self.user
         res = self.serializer.update(employee, dict())
         mocked_update.assert_called_once_with(employee, dict())
         mocked_update_shift_type.assert_called_once_with(employee, None)
         self.assertEqual(res, employee)
```